# Error While Pllotting over globe using matplotlib and contourf

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, shapely

I was trying to plot some data over the entire globe using geostationary projection. However, I got the following error. It seems to have some issues with the border areas. I am currently new to python and unable to figure out the same.

```
import h5py
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
 
# First get data from HDF5 file with h5py:
fn = '..../3DIMG_03MAY2019_0230_L1B_STD_V01R00.h5'


with h5py.File(fn) as f:
    # retrieve image data:
    image = 'IMG_TIR1'
    image2 = 'IMG_TIR2'
    lon = f['Longitude'][:]*0.01
    lat = f['Latitude'][:]*0.01
    img_arr = f[image][0, :, :]
    img_arr2 = f[image2][0, :, :]
    
    # get _FillValue for data masking
    img_arr_fill = f[image].attrs['_FillValue'][0]
    img_arr_fill2 = f[image2].attrs['_FillValue'][0]

    sat_long = f.attrs['Nominal_Central_Point_Coordinates(degrees)_Latitude_Longitude'][1]
    sat_hght = f.attrs['Nominal_Altitude(km)'][0] * 1000.0  # (for meters)
    bt_lut_tir1 = np.array(f[image+str('_TEMP')])
    bt_lut_tir2 = np.array(f[image2+str('_TEMP')])
print('Done reading HDF5 file')

# Use np.ma.masked_equal with integer values to
# mask '_FillValue' data in corners:
img_arr_m = np.ma.masked_equal(img_arr, img_arr_fill)
img_arr_m2 = np.ma.masked_equal(img_arr2, img_arr_fill2)
lon_m = np.ma.masked_equal(lon, 327.67)
lat_m = np.ma.masked_equal(lat, 327.67)

# BT from LUT
def count2bt_lut_tir1(count):
    return bt_lut_tir1[count]
def count2bt_lut_tir2(count):
    return bt_lut_tir2[count]
bt_tir1_lut = count2bt_lut_tir1(img_arr_m)
bt_tir2_lut = count2bt_lut_tir2(img_arr_m2)

######### Plotting 
# # Create Geostationary plot with cartopy and matplotlib  

map_proj = ccrs.Geostationary(central_longitude=sat_long,satellite_height=sat_hght)

ax = plt.axes(projection=map_proj)
ax.set_global()
ax.coastlines(color='black',linewidth = 0.5)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, edgecolor='white', linewidth=0.25)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.STATES,edgecolor = 'red',linewidth = 0.5)
ax.gridlines(color='black', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--', linewidth=0.75, draw_labels=True)
plt.title('Brightness Temperature(K) in TIR1 (10.8 micron)') #\n' +
cb = ax.contourf(lon_m,lat_m,bt_tir1_lut,cmap = 'jet',transform = ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.colorbar(cb)
plt.show()
```

I got the following error while running the above code:

```
---------------------
PredicateError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/anaconda3/envs/rttov/lib/python3.9/site-packages/shapely/predicates.py:15, in BinaryPredicate.__call__(self, this, other, *args)
     14 try:
---> 15     return self.fn(this._geom, other._geom, *args)
     16 except PredicateError as err:
     17     # Dig deeper into causes of errors.

File ~/anaconda3/envs/rttov/lib/python3.9/site-packages/shapely/geos.py:584, in errcheck_predicate(result, func, argtuple)
    583 if result == 2:
--> 584     raise PredicateError("Failed to evaluate %s" % repr(func))
    585 return result

PredicateError: Failed to evaluate <_FuncPtr object at 0x7fb67e380f40>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TopologicalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/anaconda3/envs/rttov/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py:339, in BaseFormatter.__call__(self, obj)
    337     pass
    338 else:
--> 339     return printer(obj)
    340 # Finally look for special method names
    341 method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
...
     37             "Likely cause is invalidity of the geometry %s" % (
     38                 self.fn.__name__, repr(geom)))
     39 raise err

TopologicalError: The operation 'GEOSContains_r' could not be performed. Likely cause is invalidity of the geometry <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x7fb5c0ae45b0>
```

I am attaching the HDF file I have used for plotting.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16LX6wErokHjS9nc4EBepLgLEB1sqCgQK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What error? Please copy and paste the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) into your question as a code block. And please read the guide to creating a [mre] - this is a ton of code, most of which is irrelevant to the question. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I have edited the code with the relevant information. Thanks !

Comment: Please go through the work yourself of isolating the issue by iteratively removing code and finding the problem. See also this guide for perspective: [crafting a minimal bug report](//matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports). Thanks!